# Example in Modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

> I am looking for an example of a ring where $M_1$ and $M_2$ are two Modules over that ring but their union isn't.

I was thinking of using the fact that any group is a module over $\mathbb{Z}$, and that $\mathbb{Q}$ is also a module over $\mathbb{Z}$ but I'm not sure.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about taking any field $F$ and$$M_1=\{(x,0)\,|\,x\in F\}\text{ and }M_2=\{(0,x)\,|\,x\in F\}?$$

Comment: As a way to visualise this, this could basically mean you take the axes in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Of course with simply the two axes you will not have a module (or in this case, we often say vector space) as it isn't closed.

Comment: Im not seeing what condition fails when i do the union.

Comment: @PedroMiguelSantos $(1,0),,(0,1)\in M_1\cup M_2$, but $(1,0)+(0,1)=(1,1)\notin M_1\cup M_2$.

Comment: Hm alright thx !! , i was doing the union of them wrong.